# Starting azure data factory with incoming parameter which is a json

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to start my data factory with parameters. For that I defined a parameter "param" in my factory. The parameter is of type string and contains a json object like this

```
{
  "url": "http://mySpecialFile.csv",
  "name": "testing"
  "destination: "farAway"
}
```

Now how can I a access these values in my factory. Is it necessary to define for each attribue a variable? And can I extract for example the value of url? I tried it like this

```
(@json(@pipeline().parameters.param).url)
```

But this does not work, it will write this value into the variable?
Is there better way to access the incoming json object? Also if I define for each json entry a variable I need to change my factory if the json changes?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Data factory pipeline parameter for `Json object type` of data there is Data type called **Object**.

Here I created Pipeline parameter named **json** with `Object data type` and your sample value.

[image]

from this parameter to access particular value you can use dynamic parameter like `@pipeline().parameters.json['value_which_you_want']`

e.g. `@pipeline().parameters.json['url']`,`@pipeline().parameters.json['name']`,`@pipeline().parameters.json['destination']`

[image]

And it is fetching proper data.

[image]